# Trouble running .Java file

Tags: java

I have a `.java` file known as "Warning.java" and its location is "C:\Users\chaos\Desktop\NEO-HACK" and I'm trying to run it using "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" but everytime I try to open the file I get an error message saying

> "Error: Could not find or load main class
>   C:\Users\chaos\Desktop\NEO-HACK\Warning.java".

Here's the source code for my .Java file:

```
/*
This is the warning file
*/
public class Warning
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.print("NEO-HACK ACTIVATED");
    }
}
```

Comment: what  is the command yo running ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile the code to a .class file before you run.  You don't *run* .java files.

Please go through the [Hello World tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) thoroughly.

Comment: How do I compile it to a .class file?

Comment: Go through the link I posted, please.

Comment: So I was going through your link and so far so good but then it asked me to enter the command "javac Warning.java" and when I did I got an error saying "'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Yeha, that means that JAVA_HOME/bin is not on your Windows PATH.  (I'll assume you're running Windows.)  Work through this; you can't write Java without being able to run Hello World.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile a .java file to a .class file (Byte code), you need JDK(Java Development Kit) installed on your system. It seems you use Windows OS. Then, conventionally you will find this jdk folder at `Program Files/Java/` (or `Program Files(x86)/Java` if you installed 32-bit JDK) if installed. In this JDK folder, you'll find a `bin` folder inside which you will have java compiler `javac`. If you want to compile your java code, you need to paste the java file in this `javac` containing folder i.e. `bin` and then from command prompt you will go to the path, compile using `javac` and run using `java`

```
>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin>javac Warning.java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin>java Warning
```

But, what if you want to compile and run java file that is placed at any location in your system? For this we need to set java `bin` path to Environment Variable.

Go to *System Properties> Advanced tab* and press '*Environment Variables*' button.
Under System Variables, You will find `Path` variable. Select it and press edit button. Add an entry of your JDK's bin location. For me it is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin
```

This entry must be separated by semi-colon(;) from previous entries.
Press OK.

And now if you go to command prompt and type `javac` you will get all the options under javac. This makes sure that jdk's bin content are now accessible from anywhere in your PC.

```
C:\Users\chaos\Desktop\NEO-HACK>javac Warning.java
C:\Users\chaos\Desktop\NEO-HACK>java Warning
```

Hope this post simplified your Learning!!